# One-way randomized communication complexity of Greater-Than

Tags: reference-request, communication-complexity

Let $\mathrm{GT}_n:\{0,1\}^n \times \{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}$ be the greater than function: $\mathrm{GT}_n(x,y)=1$ exactly when the positive integer whose binary representation is $x$ is greater than the positive integer whose binary representation is $y$.

It is well-known that the randomized communication complexity of $\mathrm{GT}_n$ is $\Theta(\log n)$. Several references claim that the randomized *one-way* communication complexity of $\mathrm{GT}_n$ is $\Theta(n)$, but I am unable to find a reference that actually contains a proof. It is easy to show a $\Omega(n/\log n)$ lower bound by a reduction from INDEX, and this is done in a paper by [Kremer, Nisan, and Ron](http://www.eng.tau.ac.il/%7Edanar/Public-pdf/KNR-fix.pdf). They also claim that the proof of the $\Omega(n)$ lower bound appears in a paper by [Miltersen, Nisan, Safra, and Wigderson](https://www.brics.dk/RS/94/41/BRICS-RS-94-41.pdf). The latter paper uses a round-elimination lemma to show a $\frac{n^{1/k}}{120^k}$ lower bound on the $k$-round communication complexity of $\mathrm{GT}_n$ but never gets around to proving the base case somehow (see Theorem 14), and the base case is all I am asking for. They also claim this is an unpublished result of Yao, but as far as I know that result may never have been written down.

Surely at some point someone wrote down a proof of this lower bound? The closest I could find (with help from Clément Canonne) is [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.08946) showing a lower bound on the quantum one-way communication complexity of $\mathrm{GT}_n$ and that just seems like an overkill.

Comment: Can you email Andrew Yao?

Comment: lol good one, but maybe I will pass on emailing Yao to dig out something from over 26 years ago. if anything I might email MNSW to ask where the base case of their induction went. but this seems so basic, someone must've actually written down a proof?

Comment: A few papers (including MNSW) also reference the (Rusian) Master's Thesis of D.V. Smirnov (1988) for the round-complexity tradeoff, but unfortunately it is nowhere to be found (even if one does speak Russian): https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/27732/reference-for-unpublished-but-quoted-manuscript

Comment: Ask one of the younger folks that work in communication complexity? How about asking Anup Rao at UW or perhaps even Noam Nisan who wrote the book?

Comment: @ChandraChekuri seems one of the younger CC folks wrote an answer here :)

Comment: Amit will be flattered I assume :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the MNSW proof carefully, the base case can be taken to be the trivial fact that a $0$-round protocol for $\textrm{GT}_n$ with $n = 1$ requires one bit of communication.

If the goal is simply to convince oneself from first principles that $\textrm{R}^\to(\textrm{GT}_n) = \Omega(n)$, this is immediate by reduction from the AUGMENTED-INDEX problem. An $\Omega(n)$ one-way lower bound for AUG-INDEX boils down to the chain rule for mutual information. For a discussion of AUG-INDEX, see, e.g., Section 3.4 of Jelani Nelson's PhD thesis ([https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~minilek/publications/papers/phd_thesis.pdf](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Eminilek/publications/papers/phd_thesis.pdf)).

Comment: Regarding the first point, I don't see how that goes? Plugging $k=1$ in the argument, we get "a $[1, n/120,n/10]$ for $\mathrm{GT}_n$ implies [...] a $[0,n,n]$ protocol for $\mathrm{GT}_1$". That does lead to a contradiction (since the way it's defined, a $0$-round protocol is impossible: 0 messages), but is that a valid base case in the induction? Because in that case I can start at $k=0$ with $[0,2^{2^n},2^{2^n}]$ if I want -- still impossible...

Comment: Also, for Augmented-Index, doesn't Jelani's thesis refer to the MNSW paper for the proof? (there is a self-contained bound in a 2014 paper of Feldman and Xiao, though: arxiv.org/abs/1402.6278), using mutual information as you point out)

Comment: Thanks, it’s true that starting from Augmented Index makes the lower bound trivial. The MNSW proof still puzzles me a little, but I guess the round elimination lemma contains a lower bound for augmented index as a special case. @ClementC the point seems to be that the $n$ in $[0,n,n]$ and the $n$ in $\mathrm{GT}_n$ are tied together.

Comment: @SashoNikolov I again am not sure -- maybe I am misunderstanding what is written, but if they are linked together the proof doesn't really make sense to me. I.e., you would need $[k-1, n^{1/(k-1)}/120^{k-1} , n^{1/(k-1)}/120^{k-1} ]$ in what is written after _"Using  the  round  elimination  lemma  this  implies  a"_ not $[k-1, n^{1/k}/120^{k-1} , n^{1/k}/120^{k-1} ]$ -- and the last part of the sentence linking $n'$ to $n$ to get the contradiction would be redundant.

Comment: Don't go by the literal statement inside the proof of Theorem 19 (JCSS version of the paper), instead look at Lemma 13 and notice how $m$ and $a$ must be related in order to apply that lemma.

Comment: Oh, shoot. The jounal version has restrictions on the parameters (I was only looking at the non-paywalled version linked in the post -- where that's lemma 11, which doesn't have any (?)) @chax

Answer (score 3):

The Ph.D. thesis of Pranab Sen ([http://www.tcs.tifr.res.in/~pgdsen/pages/phdthesis/thesis.pdf](http://www.tcs.tifr.res.in/%7Epgdsen/pages/phdthesis/thesis.pdf)) provides a $\Omega(n^{1/t}t^{-2})$ lower bound for $t$ round bounded error CC for Greater-than. I think the proof covers the case when $t=1$.

In addition, there is a $\Omega(n^{1/t}t^{-3})$ for quantum CC in the same thesis.